# SecItemDelete Blocking Indefinitely

Tags: objective-c, macos, security, keychain, xcode10

I'm attempting to delete stored passwords from the keychain by using `SecItemDelete`. I create a query dictionary using `NSMutableDictionary`, which I then bridge to `CFDictionaryRef` when passing it to `SecItemDelete`. But once I make the call it never returns and just blocks the thread. I've never experienced anything like this, it's so odd.

```
NSMutableDictionary *query = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
query[(id)kSecClass] = (id)kSecClassGenericPassword;
query[(id)kSecAttrService] = service;
query[(id)kSecAttrAccount] = account;

OSStatus status = SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query);
```

Comment: Any chance there is some kind of kSecAttrAccessControl setting on that, which may prompt for user authentication ?  Not sure why else it could block.

Comment: Does an attribute set for kSecAttrAccessControl cause SecItemDelete to block? Regardless, I am only setting a couple properties, all of which except for the value data is in the query dictionary.

Comment: if the access control is set to have UI user authentication, then yes I think the call can block waiting for the user to enter a device password or Touch ID or whatever.  I would imagine it would be the same for deletion as it would be for access or updates.  But I think that field would have had to be set explicitly when creating/updating the record previously.  I'm having a hard time thinking of anything else which could block.